# How to get the real size of video inside the MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a `MPMoviePlayerController` that is being used to play videos.  I'm using `subviews` to create watermark labels to place over the video. I need the watermarks to be on top of the actual video though not the black space to the sides or top of the video.

I know that I can use the `naturalSize` to get the original video dimensions.  However, when the player view is larger than the natural size, the video stretches to fit the view.  Is there a way to get the size of the stretched video in the player view?  If I know the real size of the video, I should be able to calculate the coordinates for placing the watermarks properly on top of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size of the movie with the property naturalSize.

```
moviePlayer.naturalSize.height  //to get the height of the frame player
```

UPDATE!!

Hope it helps

```
 -(CGRect)getResizedVideoFrame:(CGRect )naturalSize andPlayerViewSize:(CGRect)playerSize {
    float resVi = naturalSize.size.width / naturalSize.size.height;
    float resPl = playerSize.size.width / playerSize.size.height;
    return (resPl > resVi ? CGRectMake(0, 0, naturalSize.size.width * playerSize.size.height/naturalSize.size.height, playerSize.size.height) : CGRectMake(0, 0,playerSize.size.width, naturalSize.size.height * playerSize.size.width/naturalSize.size.width));
 }
```

Comment: The naturalSize gives me the native size of the video (640x480 in one particular case).  However, when I put the video into fullscreen, naturalSize still gives me 640x480, when I want the size of the video on the screen (which is scaled to fit the screen).  In the case of fullscreen video, the actual video size seems to be the full width of the device in landscape, and almost the full height of the device.

Comment: You need to create an algorithm to get the resized frame size, in base of the natural size and the moviePlayer view size

Comment: I updated my answer with the algorithm i suggest, just call it width two arguments, the natural size of the video and the player frame, if it is full screen set the full screen frame :)

Comment: That is very close.  The method above gives me the proper video width, but I get "nan" for the height.

Comment: Nevermind.  It looks like I was passing the wrong value into the method.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: naturalSize returns 0! Any clue??. I tried with `MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification`, but it effects the default movie  controllers. Actually it hides the seeking bar. Hard to believe that it might ios bug!. Please help..

Comment: @jeekOnline You are trying with a file or a playlist??? it might be that the player isn't initializeed yet... can you show me your code???

Comment: @Calleth'Zion' : Thanks for reply. I am trying to read video from file.(stored in Cache directory). Here is my code : http://justpaste.it/jqcb Thanks again... :-)'

Comment: the problem is that you are updating the frame of the player without respecting ratio... not sure what U want to accomplish, you want that the video adapts to the natural height size?

Comment: @Calleth'Zion' : I want video width to be fit screen width and video height should be its natural size. Why because its view controller will dynamically take the video files with different size/aspect ratio. As per requirement we need controllers for few videos and not for other videos (determined by a flag). Can you please share the corrected code. Thanks in advance...

Comment: as you are modifying the frame, i think you just have to play with the scaling mode, if you do set the frame with the whole width, but not  respecting ratio, it means the heigh wouldn't be the right one and the video would show blackspace... then try changing this line "moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;"